# OrmLite upsert from table

Tags: servicestack

Currently `Save()` API offers upsert behaviour when passing in a collection but is there anyway to make it work when inserting from another table?

The way I upsert with raw PostgreSQL is like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO customers (name, email)
SELECT name, email FROM other_table
ON CONFLICT (name) 
DO 
   UPDATE SET email = EXCLUDED.email;
```

OrmLite supports `ON CONFLICT` but I can't see any way to chain that into an update using `EXCLUDED`.

Is there a way to achieve this type of functionality with the fluent API without reading the collection into memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no typed API support for this in OrmLite and likely wont be as it's nigh impossible to provide a good typed cross-platform abstraction to handle the different capabilities & permutations of this feature in RDBMS's that support Upsert.

You're going to have to execute the Upsert SQL Query you want using [OrmLite Custom SQL APIs](http://nigh%20impossible) which you can use with OrmLite's typed [`Column<T>` and `Table<T>` APIs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#typed-columnt-and-tablet-apis) to include typed Table & Column references in adhoc SQL.